# How to scale a background image and fade text on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code that fades a div with a `class="BlogImage"` but instead of fade, I want it to zoom `transform: scale(1)` to `transform: scale(1.2)` and not sure how to go about it.

Any code example to achieve the scaling? Would be even better if it can fade as well as zoom (scale) while scrolling.

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    jQuery(".BlogImage").css("opacity", 1 - jQuery(window).scrollTop() / 450);
});
```

FYI, This is the html and I want to zoom the background image and fade the text:

```
<div class="BlogImage" style="background: url('images/ocean.jpg');">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h2>This is a blog title</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z4fk9upf/

Comment: Please try this method :

jQuery(".BlogImage").css('transform', 'scale(' + 1 - jQuery(window).scrollTop() / 450 + ')');

Comment: Nothing happens. Would JSFiddle help if I create?

Comment: Yes, Please create jsfiddle. I will update it

Comment: Added https://jsfiddle.net/z4fk9upf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to simulate the effect you are after:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){

    $(".BlogImage")
      .css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 450)
      .css("background-size", (100 + 100 * $(window).scrollTop() / 450) + "%");

});
```

```css
.BlogImage {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top : 10em;"></div>
<div class="BlogImage"></div>
<div style="margin-top : 25em;"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is how I might update your fiddle:

```js
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){

    jQuery(".BlogImage")
      .css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 450)
      .css("background-size", (100 + 100 * jQuery(window).scrollTop() / 250) + "%");

});
```

```css
.BlogImage {
    background-image: url(http://doc.jsfiddle.net/_downloads/jsfiddle-desktop-1440x900-a.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    /*background-size: cover;*/
    /*background-attachment: fixed;*/
    position: relative;
    min-height: 250px;
    background-position: center center;
}

.page-header {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    color:#fff;
    padding:50px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="Blog">
  <div class="BlogImage">
    <div class="page-header">
    <h2>This is a blog title</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
  <p>This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy.&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy.&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy.&nbsp;</p>
<p>This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy.&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy.&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy.&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy.&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy.&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy.&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy.&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy.&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy.&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy.&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy.&nbsp;</p>
<p>This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy.&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy.&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy.&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy.&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy.&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy.&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy&nbsp;This is the&nbsp;description of the blog for dummy.&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes but I have the css class which overrides the scaling. How should I go about it? `.BlogImage {background-size: cover !important;}`. Please see the https://jsfiddle.net/z4fk9upf/1/  and note that without `!important`, there's an override and the image won't display in full.

Comment: With this solution, you might not need the scaling :-)

Comment: btw, it seems to zoom in from left corner. how do I make it zoom from the center? something like `blog.invisionapp.com/typography-stranger-things`

Comment: did you add the **background-position: center center;**

Comment: Done. Thank you so much :)